# Uncaught TypeError: JSON.parse(...) is null

Tags: reactjs

Getting

> Uncaught TypeError: JSON.parse(...) is null for below React function.

Please help

```
addItem = () => {
    var cart = this.state.cart;
    cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    cart.push(this.state.input);
    this.setState({
      cart,
    });
    console.log(cart);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
  };
```

Comment: Try `cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart") || '[]');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check not null before parsing

```
if(localStorage.getItem("cart") !== null){
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
 }
```